# PHP Regular expression to match a string within any string so any character(s) in front and back

Tags: php, string, expression

It sounds like it should be simple and obvious and yet I can't find any simple solution to match any character(anything) in front of, and after the matching string.

I am trying to check if $j['comment'] contains certain strings (case insensitive) with names and then save the name to a new variable to output it in bold in a different position in HTML table.

```
 preg_match('/john/i', $j['comment'], $matches);
 $person = "<b>".print_r($matches[0], TRUE)."</b>";

 preg_match('/mandy/i', $j['comment'], $matches);
 $person .= "<b>".print_r($matches[0], TRUE)."</b>";
```

This works but I think it doesn't work with special characters like *. Could someone help (also if you think different function would be better/simplier/faster in this case please advise)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`preg_match('/(.*)john(.*)/i', $j['comment'], $matches);`

and maybe you want to use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)